# Xpath of previous sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the text of `<value>` node from a huge xml having structure as show below. Is there anyway to write a generic xpath query if the text of node `<name>` is know to user?

```
<ReferencesServiceQualificationItem> 
  <ItemInvolvesProduct> 
    <ID>CPI000123456854</ID>  
    <DescribedBy> 
      <value>Yes</value>  
      <Characteristic> 
        <name>POTS Interconnect Match</name> 
      </Characteristic> 
    </DescribedBy>  
    <DescribedBy> 
      <value>null</value>  
      <Characteristic> 
        <name>Remediation Date</name> 
      </Characteristic> 
    </DescribedBy> 
  </ItemInvolvesProduct> 
</ReferencesServiceQualificationItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XPath, given that user know the `name` is, for example, `'POTS Interconnect Match'` :

```
//DescribedBy[Characteristic/name='POTS Interconnect Match']/value
```

Basically the above XPath search for `DescribedBy` element where `Characteristic/name` child equals `"POTS Interconnect Match"` and then return the corresponding `value` element.

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4845e8c7c7ce3958a4103a30c093087d)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<value>Yes</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the preceeding "DescribedBy" node and you have the text of the current node:

```
//DescribedBy[Characteristic/name = 'Remediation Date']/preceding-sibling::DescribedBy[1]/value
```